# Activity crashes on inflate when using a Map Fragment (kotlin)

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, kotlin

I am making an app that has many map interactions, and one of them is seeing a little map inside an Activity where the users will be able to select a point in the map and send a request to our API.

My problem is, after I made the fragment to load the google maps and added it to the activity that should show it, the Activity itself started to crash when landing on it.
Debugging the app, I see the crash occurs on the 'SetContentView' of the Activity.

Here is the XML for the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FaleConoscoActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_main_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
        android:paddingTop="70dp"
        android:paddingRight="25dp"
        android:paddingBottom="40dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/ll_main_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center">


        //Some EditTexts and Buttons


        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment"
                android:name="com.example.dumper2.MapFragment"
                tools:layout="@layout/fragment_map"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="294dp" />
        </FrameLayout>



    </LinearLayout>

    ...
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Kotlin code for the activity:

```
class CadastroDePontoActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cadastro_de_ponto)
     }



    //Some other interactions


}
```

And here are the XML and Kotlin for the fragment:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapFragment">

    <fragment
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/mapFrag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Kotlin:

```
class MapFragment : Fragment(), OnMapReadyCallback  {
    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null
    private var listener: OnFragmentInteractionListener? = null

    private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
         ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, 
        false)
        val mapFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.mapFrag)as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)

        return rootView
      }

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        if (context is OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            listener = context
        } else {
            throw RuntimeException(context.toString() + " must implement 
            OnFragmentInteractionListener")
        }
     }

    override fun onDetach() {
        super.onDetach()
        listener = null
     }

    interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        fun onFragmentInteraction(uri: Uri)
     }

    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap
    }


    companion object {
        /**
         * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
         * this fragment using the provided parameters.
         *
         * @param param1 Parameter 1.
         * @param param2 Parameter 2.
         * @return A new instance of fragment MapFragment.
         */
        // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
            MapFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                    putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                }
            }
     }

}
```

Comment: what exactly is the error message you get when the app crashes?

Comment: It's the Android's "Stopped working" default message. It gives me options to try to solve or close the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the crashlog it's just guessing, but I don't see your activity extending OnFragmentInteractionListener, so in onAttach it would throw a RuntimeException.

Comment: So it could be the possible error. I will do it and come back again after checking

Comment: Just came back to say it worked, I added an implementation to ```MapFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener``` on the activity kotlin class, then inserted the following code:


```override fun onFragmentInteraction(uri: Uri){

    }```